# How to store user input from android app to IBM cloudant

Tags: android, android-studio, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-cloud-storage

I need to develop an basic android application which will accept the data from user (data like emp name and emp id) and then I need to store that data into IBM cloudant. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a question. What have you tried? Focus on one thing at a time, would be my advice. Writing the Android application to capture the data, and then storing the data in Cloudant. Cloudant has an official [Android library](https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android) that can help.

But if all you're doing is storing data, rather than bi-directional sync, you might not even need that -- Cloudant's API is all JSON-over-HTTP(s), so it's often as simple as doing a PUT.